# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getActiveSheet' of null porque me aparece este mensaje y como puedo solucionarlo

Tags: javascript

```javascript
function LeerDatos() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp;
  var archivo = sheets.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var hoja = archivo.getActiveSheet();
  var celda = hoja.getRange("B2").getValue();
  Logger.log(celda);
}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Bienvenido/a a SOes ..cual es la entrada de tu funcion? cual es el comportamiento esperado o flujo normal? cuales son las salidas?, Te recomiendo leer [ask], recuerda que debes subir un [example], se necesitan mas antecedentes.

Comment: ¿que se supone que hace esta línea? `var sheets = SpreadsheetApp;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estas usando `getActiveSpreadSheet` y `getActiveSheet` juntos, esto solo funciona en documentos de google o formularios, para trabajar en hojas de calculo solo debes usar `getActiveSheet`.

Tu codigo quedaria asi:

```
function LeerDatos() {
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    let cell = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
    Logger.log(cell);
}
```